# Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tell me how to solve the problem of a my float panel?
[Take a look](https://tobeamerica.com/reviews-usa-tours), please.
I see [three javascript errors](https://pastebin.com/wEE4LvWB). I made a demo, the floating panel is in the lower left corner of the website.

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(window).on('load', function() {
jQ(document).ready(function () {
var x = 0;
addCircle(x);
setInterval(function () {
    if (x === 0) {
        x = 1;
    }
    addCircle(x);
    x++;
}, 1200);
});

function addCircle(id) {
jQ('body').append('<div id="' + id + '" class="circle"></div>');
jQ('#' + id).animate({
    'width': '300px',
    'height': '300px',
    'margin-top': '-143px',
    'margin-left': '-143px',
    'opacity': '0'
}, 4000, 'easeOutCirc');
setInterval(function () {
    jQ('#' + id).remove();
}, 4000);
}
});
</script>

<img class="img1" src="pic.jpg" />

 <script>
 if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
 window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
 height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
 slug: "Y3r36"
 }], "*")
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Because you already rewrite jquery onload by using `jQuery.fn.load` .when you call `jQ(window).on('load')`, the url the function.

Comment: What to do? advise please.

Comment: Remove `jQuery.fn.load`. If you want to create jquery plugin, you can use another name like `jQuery.fn.loadContainer`, `jQuery.fn.loadMainPage`...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Perhaps, the Magento problem? - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69409/magento-1-9-typeerror-this-toggleelements-togglesingle-is-not-a-function

Comment: No, this is jquery plugin. I supposed